# Gitlab: Accessing a fork of a private repository

Tags: git, gitlab

We're attempting to use a private deployment of Gitlab for a university module. Here's what we are trying to do:

- Each coursework exercise will be hosted on a private git repository (in a group)
- All students enrolled in the course will have access to that repository
- The student will fork the private repository, clone it locally and start working
- The student will push his solution to his repository
- Staff members will pull the submissions of all students and grade them (hopefully with automated grading)

All is well, except that we won't have access to the private repositories that the student forks .. We had a great idea to make each student add a public SSH key to their profile, but Alas! [It is not possible since SSH keys have to be unique to each user](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/143) .. are there any workarounds to this?

Comment: Wouldn’t the deploy key mean that all students could see each other’s repositories? That seems undesirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gitlab does have a feature called "Deploy Keys", which grant read-only access to a project, Students would need to manually add the public key to their project, but it would then provide you with access to their work.

I don't believe it would have the same restrictions as the standard user keys.

To quote their documentation "Deploy keys allow read-only access to multiple projects with a single SSH key."

Further details (https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#deploy-keys)

Comment: Thanks! Actually we had considered that option but thought it wouldn't work. After I revisited it, it turns out that after you fork a private repo there is an option to add a deploy key from one of the forked repos .. so indeed it does work :) (though a bit inconvinient having students to add the key for each excercise ...)

Comment: I agree it is a bit inconvenient, but I'm glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you seeing this now, we managed to get this done using a mix of deploy keys and groups as suggested by @jdow .. However, this solution is a bit of a hack and has some disadvantages including:

- Staff have no access to the repository
- Students have to manually enable the deploy keys for each forked repository

Therefore, I proposed a new feature called "gitlab classrooms" which I have [detailed here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/26681)